# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append' with OpenLCA

Tags: python, api, ipc, nonetype

I am using python to call functions in the software OpenLCA and processing the results outside of openLCA. openLCA provides an implementation of an JSON-RPC based protocol for inter-process communication (IPC). However, I get the following error when I am trying to change the value of the Test_Parameter to 2000: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'.

I am following the exact instructions as mentioned here: https://github.com/GreenDelta/olca-ipc.py

this is my code

```
import olca
import uuid
client = olca.Client(8080)

setup = olca.CalculationSetup()

redef = olca.ParameterRedef()
redef.name = 'Test_Parameter'
redef.value = 2000
setup.parameter_redefs.append(redef)

setup.calculation_type = olca.CalculationType.SIMPLE_CALCULATION
setup.impact_method = client.find(olca.ImpactMethod, 'ReCiPe Midpoint (H)')
setup.product_system = client.find(olca.ProductSystem, 'Test_Process')
setup.amount = 1.0


result = client.calculate(setup)
client.excel_export(result, 'hellotest.xlsx')
client.dispose(result)
```

any help would be very appreciated.

many many thanks

Comment: This means, that `setup.parameter_redefs` is `None`. For some reason initialisation does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/GreenDelta/olca-ipc.py/blob/21effee30c41a99eb18f6b348f87cff53c23ea8c/olca/schema.py#L206

It seems the client.parameter_redefs is initialized to `None`. I didn't see a defined way of initializing it through the class so maybe you're expected to do it directly?

```
setup = olca.CalculationSetup()
setup.parameter_redefs = []
```